# In android studio design view not working

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile, android-studio

[image]

In the above image, I can view the design part.

[image]

In this image, the design view is gone. I need to make it view for comfort designing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried "preview" tab?

Comment: Suggested Post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33133589/android-studio-view-both-text-and-design-preview-of-layout/60503255#60503255

Answer (score 3):

Go to **"View"** in the top menu and click on **"Tool Buttons"**. Then Click  **Preview** Tab .

You can check this [Android Studio Tips and Tricks](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just click on the right side tab named "Preview"

Answer (score 0):

if you Go to "View" in the top menu and click on "Tool Buttons" doesn't work, it must be you project not android project now, try to configure it , set manifest file or Android SDK..

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use `Code, Split, and Design` buttons to switch between the views. (Android Studio 3.6)

Those buttons have been placed in the upper right of the XML layout screen.