# Android Studio - view both Text and Design preview of layout

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio, how can I view both the text and design preview of an XML layout side by side.

I could see it by default when I installed Studio, but now that is gone, 
and I'm not sure why. I can only see or the other.

How do I re-enable it?

Comment: Look at the top right corner of the xml screen. You will have 3 options. Go for the split view. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Open your `[whatever].xml`. At the bottom you'll see `Design` and `Text`. Select `Text`. If you still can't see the actual layout, only xml, then select "`Preview`" which is located at the right of the window, between `Gradle` and `Maven Projects`.

Comment: Yeah, I just clicked Preview to see that. Thanks for the answer nonetheless.

Comment: If you cannot see Preview, add it from
"View>Tool Windows>Preview"

Comment: Like @fthdgn said, it's a tool window, so saying something like "it's to the right and beween..." isn't very useful; those things move around.

Comment: Anyone know hot to hide wire-frame window(light blue color) appear on right side of design view ?

Answer (score 32):

[image]

Click on preview while text is selected.

Comment: On my 13" MacBook Pro (purchased in 2015), the *Preview* item circled in your screen shot doesn't appear. To get to the preview window, I had to follow the advice in @fthdgn's comment to the accepted answer: "If you cannot see *Preview*, add it from *View ->Tool Windows -> Preview*"

Comment: Anyone know hot to hide wire-frame window(light blue color) appear on right side of design view ?

Answer (score 11):

[image]

At first, select your desired `.xml` layout from the `Project tab` then use *`Code, Split and Design`* buttons to switch between the views. `(Android Studio 3.6)`

Code - Display only XML part

Split- Display XML and design both

Design- Only design part

Comment: How can I make "split" the default view? Whenever I select another .xml file, AS shows the "code" view

Comment: Ok, seems like the feature is not available yet. It should become an option in the Settings / Editor / Layout Editor 
see: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/fbc5f3/any_way_to_set_default_mode_to_split_view_in/

Comment: Anyone know hot to hide wire-frame window(light blue color) appear on right side of design view ?

Answer (score 9):

[image: Design, split, and code selection buttons in Android Studio 3.6.1]

It appears that in Android 3.6.1, the buttons to select **Design**, **Split**, or **Code** have been placed in the upper right of the XML layout screen.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Select any one from the top right options to change the view of your Code and Design

Answer (score -1):

You can split the tab by right-clicking on the tab and selecting either `Split Horizontally` or `Split Vertically`. Then, you can select the `Design` tab on one and the `Text` tab on the other.